# What is the meaning of handling error in 1.5 bit ADC?

Tags: dac

In the diagram shown bellow we have 1.5 bit ADC stage. We have Vin which is an analog signal and it could be translated as `00`, `01`, or `10`.

In one bit we have only the option of 0 or 1. I can't see how it fixed an error, it's just dividing the range to more logical sections. I can't see any error fixing in here.

Is there simple practical example I could use to visualize how it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your figure shows one stage of a pipelined ADC.
[image]

The "error correction" is not an analog operation, but rather a digital operation that resolves any contradictions among the outputs of the stages. It is a correction of the error of thresholds applied in the ADC.

It is not the thresholds that are then corrected, but the digital output of the ADC stages are digitally recalculated based on redundancy among them, effectively overcoming the threshold errors.

This "error" is not to be confused with the "residual" or "quantization error" after each stage.

Conceptually, if there are 7 1-bit stages without any overlap or redundancy, there would be a 7 bit output.

When assembling a 7 bit value from the digital output of 7 stages with overlap (14 bits total), there is some redundancy to contend with, since each stage produces 1.5 bits of overlapping resolution, and 2 bits of code.

Each 1.5 bit stage has one of three values: Digital Output (-1 , 0, or +1), coded by two bits (using 3 of 4 permutations).

- +1 means "definitely well above the threshold"
- -1 means "definitely well below the threshold"
- 0 means "somewhere around the threshold"

That "0" is tentative and will be resolved by the next stage, of which its output (again one of +1,-1,0) will be used by the "digital error correction" to resolve the uncertainty.

Here is a table, from the linked page below:

[image]

As an aside, the purpose of introducing the redundancy has to do with the accuracy of placing ADC comparator thresholds and the DAC output for residual subtractors. Clearly there should be no discrepancy between the decision threshold and the generated reference for the residual.

More:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/1/1023.html

and

https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/analog/article/21775949/15bit-stages-in-pipeline-adcs (but figures are missing)

For an example, see my answer in [visualising redundancy in1.5bit pipe line ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523050/visualising-redundancy-in1-5bit-pipe-line-adc/523257#523257)

Comment: What is the effect of the redundant area to the result.
In 1.5bit We have the redundant area between -1/4 and 1/4
In 2.5bit we have redundant area betwee -7/8 and 7/8.
I'll be glad if there is some example.

Comment: @rocko445, did you have a look at the maxim link? It has a worked out example. BTW in 2.5bit I think it's +/-1/8 not 7/8.

Comment: Hello, With redundancy we are doing shifting of the 1.5 bit binary result and its called "digital error fixing",what if we have non redundant stages,Why cant we do it in non redundant stages?
even in MAXIM example we are converting the digital outputs to decimal number.but why we cant do the same thing with non redundant stages?
Thanks.

Comment: @rocko445 you can, in principle. But The issue is the tolerance/accuracy of the thresholds/reference voltages of the ADC/DAC. If they don't match or are not precise, and the input is near the threshold, you might end-up on the wrong side. And there is no chance of recovery/fixing by following stages.

Comment: Based on what you said ,and after further reading i 
understood that both of those 1.5bit redundant stages
are shifted and sumed digitaly (as you said)
Shifting and summing if basicly doing an avarage between the data from both stages.
So by doind this operation we assume the first redundant  stage and second redundant stage representing the same DATA.
Why is that?
Why do we assume that? its not the same data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "redundant stage and second redundant stage representing the same DATA". What DATA? Each stage encodes the residue from the previous stage.

Comment: Yes i agree with you, can you please give me a simple input example so i would so how redundant stages help us with handling errors?
Thanks.

Comment: I put it in an answer to your other post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523050/visualising-redundancy-in1-5bit-pipe-line-adc/523257#523257

Answer (score 2):

"Error" means the amount of the input which wasn't measured in the output!

If you have a 1-bit ADC, and it can only output 0.25V or 0.75V, and the input voltage is 0.4V, it will output 0.25V and the error is 0.15V.

By connecting another stage, you can measure the error. If the first stage says the input is 0.25V, and the second stage says the error from the first stage is 0.10V (made-up numbers), then your ADC outputs 0.35V and the remaining error is 0.05V.